# Pass input to Angular components via router

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-services, angular-router

In Angular 2, I have my routes defined in `app.module.ts`:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
  }
];
```

I also have an `app.component` which displays the menu and a search form. This `app.component` is connected to a service (`events.service.ts`) which returns an array of `events`. When the search form is submitted, `app.component` calls the service to filter the events and then grabs them:

```
getEvents(): void {
    this.eventsService.getEvents().then(events => {this.events = events});
}

onSubmit() {
    this.searchTerm = this.model.searchTerm;
    this.eventsService.search(this.searchTerm).then(res => this.getEvents());
}
```

I would like to be able to pass `this.events` from the `app.component` down to the two routes specified in `app.module` (`home` and `admin`).

My `home.component.ts` requires the same `events.service.ts`, and grabs events from it in an `onNgInit` function, but when the events in the service have been updated via the search in `app.component.ts`, the events grabbed in the initialisation of `home.component.ts` are out of date. I would like them to be synchronised.

Comment: theres 2 options, passing the data in the route parameters and via an injectable service

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot directly pass data as "input" to the route. Components which are placed "at the other side of" `<router-outlet>` are not visible in template, hence the notion of an "input" is not applicable in such cases.

The idea of router is to encode as much of application state as possible in the route. Of course, you can implement some sort of caching to avoid multiple requests for the same resource that you expect to stay the same during reasonable amount of time.

Of course, not all data can be transferred through route. For example, you usually write only some sort of identification for an entity, and then use HTTP to bring more data down based on the ID read from the route.

That said, you can keep your data in a service. From your component, save some data in a service instance which you've injected. Because services are singletons, when you inject the same service in a component which is used as a child route, you'll have the data placed in it from the parent route.

```
// componentA
this.service.data = data; // from http request, for example

// componentB
this.data = this.service.data;
```

Of course, depending on the timing of the operations above, it might happen that code in component B executes before code in component A, which means that you would grab `undefined` from `Service#data`. This is especially a common case if `data` is fetched asynchronously, which is often the case with HTTP requests.

For this, you can use observables, probably a `BehvaiorSubject` in order to grab data whenever you subscribe.

```
// service
data$ = new BehaviorSubject<T>(null) // initial value as arg

// component A
this.service.data$.next(data) // from http request, for example

// component B
this.service.data$.subscribe(data => this.data = data)
```

Now your data in component B will update as soon as data is fetched in component A, though the `data$` observable in the singleton service injected in both components.

Be sure to unsubscribe as well, although you can use `async` pipe in Angular too. In that case, Angular will handle the unsubscription for you and in most cases this is the preferred way of using observables in Angular.

Comment: I edited my question - I already try to grab the events from the service in one of the child components (`home.component.ts`) but they're not sync'd.

Comment: Use an observable, then. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since angular 7.2.0 you can pass data through the router, using  [NavigationExtras](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras)

Add state to the route definition:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    state:{...}
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
  }
];
```

But, your app bootstraps from app.module.ts, this mean that when the app is setting up in app.module.ts the services aren't still available, son you can't call the services yet.

Option 1:
Use a intermediate component, on the router you load HomeComponent_B or AdminComponent_B, and on that component, on the template you load the final component `<app-homecomponent [events]="dat from services">`

Option 2:
Better approach is use BehaviorSubject as suggested by [@Lazar Ljubenović](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46429999/1210463)